# WebStorm marks $query() of Objection.js as unresolved

Tags: javascript, api, webstorm, knex.js, objection.js

I'm currently using Objection.js with WebStorm to build a Rest API. But, when I want to make a relationQuery of Objection.js, my WebStorm shows me one out of two times that `$query()` is unresolved.

I have installed the Objection.js TypeScript, but it doesn't work. I also tried to invalidate the WebStorm cache, but no better results.

Here are some screenshots of the errors

$query() unresolved:
[image: $query() unresolved]

$query() resolved:
[image: $query() resolved]

I also watched with Visual Studio Code, and the code in the first screenshot is well detected and solved

$query() resolved inside VSCode:
[image: $query() 1 resolved inside Visual Studio Code]

I use Node 12.17, WebStorm 2020.1 and Objection 2.1.3

Hoping you can help me.

Here is the complete code snipper of the error:

```
const Users = require('../../../database/Users');
const sendReset = require('../../../email/reset');
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid');

/**
 * @api {post} /v1/users/reset ✔ Set a reset email for an account
 * @apiName resetPassword
 * @apiGroup Users
 * @apiVersion 1.0.0
 *
 * @apiParam {String} email email address of the user
 *
 * @apiSuccessExample {json} Success-Response :
 *      HTML 200 Success
 *      {
 *          "text": "success"
 *      }
 */

async function resetPassword(req, res) {
    let email = req.body["email"];
    if (email) {
        try {
            let toEdit = await Users.query().findOne("email", email);
            if (toEdit) {
                let token = nanoid(42);
                let edited = await toEdit.$query().patchAndFetch({'token': token});
                if (edited)
                    await sendReset(edited);
            }
            res.status(200).json({"message": "success"});
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(500).json({"error": "Internal server error"});
        }
    }
}

module.exports = resetPassword;
```

Users.js:

```
/*
**  Created by Frederic GOMEL on 03/03/2020 at 18:07
**  Project: api
*/

const knex = require('../init/database');
const {Model} = require('objection');

Model.knex(knex);

class Users extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return 'users';
    }

    static get jsonSchema() {
        return {
            type: 'object',
            required: ["email", "group_right", "firstName", "lastName", "token"],

            properties: {
                id: {type: 'integer'},
                email: {type: 'string'},
                group_right: {type: 'integer'},
                firstName: {type: 'string'},
                lastName: {type: 'string'},
                password: {type: ['string', 'null']},
                rfid_uid: {type: ['string', 'null']},
                token: {type: ['string', 'null']}
            }
        };
    }

    static get relationMappings() {
        const Racks = require('./Racks');
        return {
            racks: {
                relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
                modelClass: Racks,
                join: {
                    from: 'users.id',
                    through: {
                        from: 'link_users_racks.user',
                        to: 'link_users_racks.rack'
                    },
                    to: 'racks.id'
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

module.exports = Users;
```

reset.js:

```
const mail = require('../init/mails');
const twig = require('twig');

function sendReset(user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        twig.renderFile('./email/templates/resetPassword.twig', {
            name: `${user["firstName"]} ${user["lastName"]}`,
            support_email: global["config"]["support_email"],
            url: `${process.env["APP_URL"]}/activate?email=${user["email"]}&token=${user["token"]}`,
            title: `Demande de changement de mot de passe`,
            favicon: `${process.env["API_URL"]}/assets/images/favicon.ico`,
            logo: `${process.env["API_URL"]}/assets/images/logo.png`
        }, async (err, html) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                mail.sendMail({
                    sender: `JAD Technologie <${process.env["MAIL_MAIL"]}>`,
                    to: user['email'],
                    subject: `Demande de changement de mot de passe`,
                    html: html
                }).then(() => {
                    resolve();
                }).catch((err) => {
                    reject({"mail": true, err});
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports = sendReset;
```

I use Express.js 4.16.0

Comment: please share a complete code snippet as text

Comment: I edited my question